# How does a mutable array works in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm Learning Javascript from multiple ressources like FCC where i can't Understand one concept with the mutable arrays. I've got an example :

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
myArray[0]=3;  //[3,2,3]

var ourArray = [1,2,3];
ourArray[1] = 3; //[1,3,3]
```

i can't get how the `[3,2,3]` and `[1,3,3]` are created.

thanks for your help

ok, got it but what if my code looks like this :

```
var arr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [[10,11,12], 13, 14] ];
arr[3];  // equals [[10,11,12], 13, 14] arr[3][0]; // equals [10,11,12]
arr[3][0][1]; // equals 11 how the arr[3] or arr[3][0] work ?
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JS starts with 0 index.
In the first case you're replacing 1 with 3

```
[1, 2, 3]
 ^
 3
[0, 1, 2] <- indexes
```

In the second case, you're replacing 2 with 3

```
[1, 2, 3]
    ^
    3
[0, 1, 2] <- indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutable just means that each element in the array can be changed.
The number inside the brackets is the order starting with 0;

So originally myArray[0] is 1, myArray[1] is 2, myArray[2] is 3
When you do myArray[0] = 3 it sets the value in the first spot to 3, hence getting 3,2,3

Comment: ok, got it but what if my code looks like this : var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
];
arr[3]; // equals [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
arr[3][0]; // equals [10,11,12]
arr[3][0][1]; // equals 11    how the arr[3] or arr[3][0] work ?

Comment: So here you have an array, with each item inside also being an array, and one item of that also being an array! So arr[0] = [10,11,12]. and arr[3] =[[10,11,12], 13, 14] ]. You can combine the index in the brackets like arr[3][0][1]. So remember its 0 based, so you are going to get the 4th item in arr, and the 1st item inside that, and the second item inside that which is equal to 11.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `myArray[0]=3` here you are setting a value of a particular position in that array same with `ourArray[1]` so you are making changes in that array with the new values so the console gives you array with new values like in your example you defined with the name `myArray` and `ourArray` .

Answer (score 0):

Let me go through your code line by line,

`var myArray = [1,2,3];`

creates a myArray with [1, 2, 3]

`myArray[0]=3;`

index 0 of myArray is set to 3;

so myarray holds [3, 2, 3]

`var ourArray = [1,2,3];`

ourArray is created with [1, 2, 3]

`ourArray[1] = 3;`

index 1 of our array is set to 3;
 so our array holds [1, 3, 3]

**Please note that index starts with 0 and not with 1.**